# CWE-918 with Spring @Value parameters

Tags: java, spring, semgrep

After running a code scanning on my project, I see the CWE-918 vulnerability, but in the code, the parameters are retrieved from `application.properties`, so I am unsure how to solve this issue or even if it is an actual issue.

This is the code:
application.properties file:

```
proxy.host=my.proxy.host
proxy.port=1234
```

Then the config class where the scanner detects the vulnerability:

```java
public class MyProxyConfig {

    @Value("${proxy.host}")
    private String myProxyHost;
    
    @Value("${proxy.port}")
    private int myProxyPort;
    
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
    ...
    Proxy myProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(myProxyHost,myProxyPort));
    
    ...
    return myBean;
    }
}
```

The line where the vulnerability is detected is this one:

```java
Proxy myProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(myProxyHost,myProxyPort));
```

I tried looking for info about CWE-918 and to find possible fixes, one of the solutions proposed is to place those values in the code as constants, but I don't think that hardcoding the value of properties as proxy host and port is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide too many details about the supposed vulnerability, but from afar, this looks like a false positive.

If these properties are read from a configuration file that the end-user (and thus, also the attacker) can't access, there is no vulnerability here. To state it differently - if an attacker needs to gain access to a local file on your server in order to change these values, the fact that they're able to do so once gaining such access is the least of your concerns.